# Problem using CakePHP's FormHelper to Save/Edit data sequentially with one action

Tags: cakephp, controller, action, formhelper, neighbours

I'm trying to use CakePHP to create a data entry form like similar to MS Access.

The Form in my view file will always post data to a single action, and will not have a "Submit" button. So, there's no $this->Form->end().

Instead, there are two links at the end of this form, "Next" and "Previous".

My question is how can I make these two links post the form's data to my controller's action?

Answer (score 1):

Use $form->submit(), which creates a submit button, but doesn't end the form.  It appears you were using one of the convenient features of $form->end(), which if you pass it a string, will also automatically create a submit button.

```
<?php
    echo $form->create('Model');
    echo $form->input(...);
    echo $form->submit('Previous');
    echo $form->submit('Next');
    echo $form->end();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the jquery form plugin that will allow you to submit the form via ajax.  Then, in your onclick methods for your next and previous links, you could call the .submit function and submit the form.

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Here are the cake specific directions
http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/cakephp-ajax-quick-save-jquery